# plumber return base64-encoded svg

Tags: r, base64, qr-code, plumber

I'd like the plumber API endpoint to return the base64-encoded SVG contents as a clickable link.

For example,

```r
qr <- qrcode::qr_code("hello")
tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".svg")
qrcode::generate_svg(qr, tf, size = 100, foreground = "black", background = "white", show = FALSE)
txt <- paste(readLines(tf), collapse = "")
b64txt <- paste0("data:image/svg+xml;base64,", base64enc::base64encode(charToRaw(txt)))

str(txt)
#  chr "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w"| __truncated__

str(b64txt)
#  chr "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiID8+PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53M"| __truncated__
```

The primary use of *this* functionality will be to provide a "convenience"/helper function that allows the user to encode something to a QR code for easy transfer to a mobile device. (Perhaps there are other ways for some users to transfer a long formatted string from their computer to their phone, but this seems like a straight-forward way.) I'm hoping that they can paste in the text that needs to be transferred, then the plumber/swagger interface gives them a "download file" link:

> [image: example of "download file" link in plumber]

that is the self-contained base64/svg (from `b64txt` above).

I'm unable to find a combination of `@serializer` options where I can get the "Download file" link whose target is the `data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwg` contents (a self-contained SVG in this case).

For context, using `@serializer contentType list(type="image/svg+xml")` shows

> [image: plumber output with literal svg text]

and using `@serializer svg` shows empty data:

> [image: plumber svg output (with no svg text)]

---

Here's the plumber endpoint,

```r
#* Convenience function for transfer to mobile devices via QR code
#* @get /qrcode
#* @serializer svg
#* @param string
get_qrcode <- function(string = NA, res, req, ...) {
  tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".svg")
  on.exit(unlink(tf), add = TRUE)
  qr <- qrcode::qr_code(string)
  qrcode::generate_svg(qr, tf, size = 100, foreground = "black", background = "white", show = FALSE)
  txt <- paste(readLines(tf), collapse = "")
  b64txt <- paste0("data:image/svg+xml;base64,", base64enc::base64encode(charToRaw(txt)))
}
```

Comment: And presumably, merely adding `as_attachment(b64txt, 'b64txt.svg') \n }` after `paste0('data:image...`, as a suggestion, completely misses the mark.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, that provides a link but one that _downloads_ a file (not _opens_ it), and even after `write(b64txt, file="b64txt.svg")` and using `contentType list(type="application/octet")`, the contents of the file are what I want as the href's target.

Comment: Then I think, either 'such things (contents) might be deemed dangerous', or b64txt needs to be further decorated a https, and perhaps [qrcode issue #9](https://github.com/ThierryO/qrcode/issues/9) speaks to this aspirationally.